# Why are the organization of mental lexicon and lexical access interdependent?

Tags: english, psycholinguistics, lexicon

I read in Carroll ("Psychology of Language") that how the mental/internal lexicon is organized and how we access lexical information are interdependent issues.

However, he does not really specify that and I don't understand the relationship of the two. I thought aspects like frequency of the word, its phonological structure, its syntactic category etc. influence how good we retrieve it?

How are can they be interdependent issues? I would also like to read more about it.

Thank you"

Comment: Are you confusing the words interdependent and independent? I'm not sure how to parse your question otherwise.

Comment: It doesn't really matter. There isn't anything but theorizing about "the mental lexicon" and "lexical access". There are so many individual and conceptual differences that nothing useful can be said about their independence, if any.